# Shape created by OpengGL ES is larger than screen

Tags: android, zooming, opengl-es-2.0

Hi there
I am using `OpenGL ES 2.0` on android. I have created a shape but it is larger than screen. How can I set zoom size so all of my shape can be in the screen in `OpenGL ES` version `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This job (to fit the edges in OpenGL ES screen) is shader's duty. You manully code shader text and vertex code.
You should have something like this:

```
public static final String vs_Text =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
    "  v_Color = a_Color;" + 
    "}";
public static final String fs_Text =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "varying vec4 v_Color;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
       "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ) * v_Color;" +
    "  gl_FragColor.rgb *= v_Color.a;" +
    "}";
```

Please note this is a general code and you might change some parts.
For more detail please [click here](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-opengl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-8-rendering-text/).

Comment: Hi, Is this a global code our may differ in different codes?

Comment: This is a global code for these properties: color, position attribute. If you want to add other parts, if may have a different changes. Generally, yes can use this code for your codes.

Answer (score 0):

A shape may in no case be larger then screen. Screen in your case is a physical device that is designed to present visual content for you. A shape on the other hand in your case is a set of instructions that may be used to visually present something on your screen.

So the interesting part of that statement is actually how to visually present that shape. You failed to provide any information on how you "created" your shape or what it is but in most cases we are talking about points defined as 3D vectors (next to other data) from which surfaces are created and drawn on the screen. And if your shape does not fit on your screen then you should check on how you are presenting this data on the screen and possibly scale your shape.

In openGL everything is normalized and so your screen coordinates are in range `[-1.0, 1.0]` which means left side of the screen has a value of `-1.0`, right `1.0`, bottom `-1.0` and top `1.0`. You may not change that but you need to scale/transform all your points, vertices to fit your needs. To do so in ES2 we usually use matrices in vertex shader which is designed to do such operations on your GPU.

To use matrices I am sure you can search around a bit so you insert a uniform in your vertex shader and connect it with your code. Then you should look at what tools to use to manipulate matrices. You will most likely find a tool that will then give you nice ability for presenting objects in orthographical or frustum projections. Further more it might help you in some case to move your object away a bit by using translate methods on your matrix.

To fix your issue (shape being drawn off the screen) with matrices you have multiple ways:

- Use `ortho` matrix and set large enough border parameters such as `left = -100.0, right = 100.0...` should make the shape look 100 times smaller
- Use `scale` matrix to reduce the size of shape
- Use `frustum` matrix with some field of view and move your shape away by combining it with `translation` matrix

It really depends on scenario which to use but choose whatever makes most sense (in your case you have again failed to provide any information).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By shape I mean a sin wave from -3.14 to 3.14. I have used matrix shader but did not worked.

Comment: @StephenFrosty You must have used it incorrectly then. It will be near impossible to give you additional help without you providing some code and description of both your current result and your expected result.